# Erro na matriz como parâmetro da função

Tags: c, matriz

Boa noite.

Estou com um problema ao usar uma matriz como parâmetro em minhas funções. Eu tenho em uma função que tem uma matriz int como parâmetro, quando chamo a matriz passo uma matriz original, e na função manipulo o parâmetro e salvo em um arquivo externo, o problema esta na parte de manipulação, quando eu manipulo o parâmetro, os valores da matriz original estão sendo modificados também, e não é para eles serem modificados, é pra só o valor da matriz parâmetro estar sendo modificado. Pode ter ficado meio confuso mas acredito que vendo o código vão entender:

Parte em que crio a matriz original:

```
FILE *pgm;
do
{
    char arq[30];
    printf("Digite o nome de arquivo para leitura com .pgm no fim(ex: imagem.pgm): ");
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    gets(arq);
    pgm = fopen(arq, "r");
}while(pgm == NULL);

char tipo[5];
fscanf(pgm, "%s", &tipo);
fscanf(pgm, "%d %d", &col, &lin);
fscanf(pgm, "%d", &escala);
int img[lin][col];
for(i = 0; i < lin; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
        fscanf(pgm, "%d", &img[i][j]);
    }
}

fclose(pgm);
```

Função que utiliza uma matriz como parâmetro:

```
void escurerClarear(char tipo[], int mat[lin][col]){

float mult;
system("cls");
printf("Informacoes:\n\nPara clarear/escurecer e necessario fornecer um multiplicador com ou sem casa decimal\n\nEsse multiplicador deve ser maior que 0\n\nUm valor abaixo de 1 escurece a imagem e acima de 1 clareia\n\nDigite um multiplicador: ");
scanf("%f", &mult);
while(mult < 0)
{
    printf("\n\nO multiplicador deve possuir valor positivo: ");
    scanf("%f", &mult);
}
for(i = 0; i < lin; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
        if((mult * mat[i][j]) > escala)
        {
            mat[i][j] = escala;
        }
        else
        {
            mat[i][j] = mult * mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

salvarImg(tipo, mat);}
```

Chamando a função:

```
escurerClarear(tipo, img);
```

Após executar a função os valores da matriz img estão sendo trocados e não quero modificalos, quero modificar apenas os valor da matriz mat, do parâmetro

EDIÇÃO::

```
int temp[lin][col];
for(i = 0; i < lin; i++)
            {
                for(j = 0; j < col; j++)
                {
                    temp[i][j] = img[i][j];
                }
            }
            escurerClarear(tipo, temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando se passa uma matriz para uma funcao na verdade estamos passando o endereco de memoria do primeiro elemento da matriz, portanto esta passando um parametro por referencia e os valores irao ser alterados dentro da funcao que foi chamada (`escurerClarear`).

O que voce vai ter que fazer é criar uma outra matriz bidimensional do mesmo tamanho da tua matriz original, depois copiar os dados da matriz original para a matriz recem criada e depois passar ela para a funcao.

Antes de chamar a tua funcao `escurerClarear` copia os dados da matriz original para outra matriz com um laço for:

```
for(i = 0; i < lin; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < col; j++)
        matriz_temporaria[i][j] = matriz_original[i][j];
```

Apos isso passe a variavel `matriz_temporaria` do mesmo modo que passava a matriz original e seja feliz.

```
altera_matriz(matriz_temporaria);
```

Ou se preferir faça isso dentro da sua funcao `escurerClarear` mesmo, o que voce achar melhor.

Aqui vai um exemplo de um pequeno programa que fiz para voce entender melhor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const int lin = 3;
const int col = 3;

int altera_matriz(int matriz[][col]);

int main ()
{
    int i, j;

    int matriz_original[lin][col];
    int matriz_temporaria[lin][col];

    for(i = 0; i < lin; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < col; j++)
            matriz_original[i][j] = j;

    for(i = 0; i < lin; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < col; j++)
            matriz_temporaria[i][j] = matriz_original[i][j];

    altera_matriz(matriz_temporaria);

    for(i = 0; i < lin; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < col; j++)
            printf("matriz_original[%i][%i]:%i \n", i, j, matriz_original[i][j]);

    for(i = 0; i < lin; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < col; j++)
            printf("matriz_temporaria[%i][%i]:%i \n", i, j, matriz_temporaria[i][j]);

    return 0;
}

int altera_matriz(int matriz[][col])
{
    matriz[0][0] = 0;
    matriz[0][1] = 0;
    matriz[0][2] = 0;

    matriz[1][0] = 0;
    matriz[1][1] = 0;
    matriz[1][2] = 0;

    matriz[2][0] = 0;
    matriz[2][1] = 0;
    matriz[2][2] = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eu imaginei que você algo parecido, porque ja vi funções que passavam a matriz como ponteiro , exemplo *img, vou tentar fazer isso que você disse

Comment: @Filipe Tranquilo, qualquer coisa posta ai.

Comment: Então, eu tentei fazer isso ai, mas o programa para de funcionar, trava

Comment: Vou atualizar a pergunta pra vc ver

Comment: @Filipe Cara, nao consegui identificar o erro, tu consegue depurar o teu programa e ver em que linha esta travando?

Comment: Eu dei uma pesquisa, e parece que não tem como passar valores de matriz pra matriz, só por ponteiro

Comment: @Filipe Da uma olhada na minha resposta, dei uma editada. Agora acho que voce vai entender melhor. Compila aquele programinha que eu fiz para ver que funciona de boa.

Comment: @Filipe Conseguiu?